# Relation between Judges 4 and Joshua 11

Tags: contradiction, judges, joshua, chronology

In Judges 4:2 (NASB)

> So the Lord sold them into the hand of **Jabin king** of Canaan, who reigned **in Hazor**; and the commander of his army was Sisera, who lived in Harosheth-hagoyim.

From Joshua 11:1-11 we read that both a king named Jabin and Hazor were destroyed

> Then it came about, when Jabin king of Hazor heard about it, that he sent word to Jobab king of Madon, to the king of Shimron, to the king of Achshaph, 2 and to the kings who were of the north in the hill country, and in the Arabah—south of Chinneroth and in the lowland, and on the heights of Dor on the west— 3 to the Canaanite on the east and on the west, and the Amorite, the Hittite, the Perizzite, and the Jebusite in the hill country, and the Hivite at the foot of Hermon in the land of Mizpeh. 4 Then they came out, they and all their armies with them, as many people as the sand that is on the seashore, with very many horses and chariots. 5 So all of these kings gathered together, and came and encamped together at the waters of Merom, to fight against Israel.
>
> 6 Yet the Lord said to Joshua, “Do not be afraid because of them, for tomorrow at this time I am going to turn all of them over to Israel as good as dead; you shall hamstring their horses and burn their chariots with fire.” 7 So Joshua and all the people of war with him came upon them suddenly at the waters of Merom, and attacked them. 8 And the Lord handed them over to Israel, so that they defeated them, and pursued them as far as Great Sidon, and Misrephoth-maim, and the Valley of Mizpeh to the east; and they struck them until no survivor was left to them. 9 And Joshua did to them just as the Lord had told him; he hamstrung their horses and burned their chariots with fire.
>
> **10 Then Joshua turned back at that time and captured Hazor, and struck its king with the sword; for Hazor previously was the head of all these kingdoms. 11 They struck every person who was in it with the edge of the sword, utterly destroying them; there was no one left who breathed. And he burned Hazor with fire**.

Is Judges 4:2 speaking of the same person (king Jabin) and location (Hazor)? If yes, how can that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names in royal families are often repeated, even in modern times.  Note the comments of the Cambridge Bible commentary on Josh 11:1:

> **Jabin** This was an hereditary and official title of the chief of
> Hazor. It denotes “the wise” or “intelligent” Here we find a king of
> the same name at a considerably later date (Jdg 4:2).

Thus, it is unnecessary to assume the two Jabin's are the same person.

The fact that the king was killed (at the time of Joshua) does not prevent the restoration of the monarchy by others at a later date (during the time of the Judges) and using the same titles, etc, in an attempt to foster unity with the past.

Further, the two records in Joshua 11 and Judges 4 are separated by many years; ancient cities were destroyed and rebuilt many times and that may have occurred here.  This occurred because the site of ancient cities was due to advantages of position including protection, and water supply and the fact that a city was destroyed did not cease to make it a good site.  When archaeologists dig through ancient layers, they often find many cases of old cities being rebuilt many times.

Comment: Right... What about Hazor? (That I think to be the hardest part of to answer)

Comment: right it I'm pointing to the fact that Hazor was fully destroyed in Joshua 11, not just the king

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - answer updated accordingly

Comment: "restoration of the monarchy" including the city buildings or they weren't all destroyed? "he burned Hazor with fire"; What about the people? "there was no one left who breathed"

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - it was along time later.  Cities were located in good positions and when the city was destroyed, it was often rebuilt by others because of it water supply and other advantages.  many ancient cities were destroyed and rebuilt many times.

Comment: Dottard can you improve the answer with that last consideration from the comment so that I can accept it?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - Updated as requested.